# Postman displays xsi:nil as an empty element

Tags: web-services, soap, postman, soapui

I'm having an issue(dont know if this is actually an issue and I've looked on the postman website but cant find anything) when I send a get from a web service, the xml that is brought back returns `<elementA></elementA>`. When I do the same request on SOAPUI it returns `<elementA xsi:nil='true'/>`.

Is there a setting in postman to allow it recognise xsi:nil?